# Display problem in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: display, display-resolution, 18.04

This is what I get after logging in:

[image]

I was using Ubuntu 17.04 peacefully, until the moment it prompted me to install Bionic Beaver. I've had problems with Ubuntu before like not getting the resolution of my monitor, which I fixed by using xrandr command and so on. But after updating, it just made my life worse. I am not able to do anything because of this glitch. Someone please help me change this.

Comment: After entering your password but before pressing `Enter` click the gear next to the `Sign in` button and choose a different desktop environment. Repeat this until you find the one that works perfectly. For me it is `Unity`.

Comment: Is it the same problem as this? https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1766137

Comment: @Steve Yes. Please tell me how to fix it

Comment: @ArunachaleshwarK It says right at the top: “WORKAROUND: After typing an incorrect password, click Cancel, then click your name, then enter your password again”

Comment: @Steve let me try it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After going through this, https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1766137 I was able to resolve my problem. Thanks to @Steve and the community people for helping me out.